# Mac Menu Bar Covering Options

Tags: macos

I'm new to my Mac and using Flash.

When I go to the Publish Settings option I expect to see something like this:

[image: Expected]

But, instead of seeing that nice bar at the top saying "Publish Settings" and the like, I get:

[image: Actual]

While this isn't completely terrible with respect to functionality, it still messes with my head.  I need the comfort of having that bar at the top.  And in other programs, I've periodically experienced an unusable window, where some option I needed was in a place I couldn't reach.

On Windows, I'd right-click the thingy in the taskbar and select "Move" and move that window where I want it.  How do I do something similar on my Mac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's strange behavior! Maybe this will work: Change your screen resolution in the Display panel in the System Preferences. Try displaying that dialog again, and then change it back to whatever resolution it was.

Comment: Thanks! This worked!  Bonus points: Isn't there a simpler way though?  To readjust my screen resolution every time this happens seems to be kind of a lot of work compared to just doing the right-click move thing.

Comment: Your absolutely right. While checking for a solution, the problem occurred here. I'm curious if this is a bug in Flash itself. Have you tried to restart Adobe Flash after changing (and re-changing) your display resolution? After I restarted flash the problem was gone..

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it, and I'll add "can't move windows" to my list of things OSX can't do but my Windows box can. ;)

Comment: I don't believe you can move windows in Mac OS X with the keyboard without third-party software such as Mercury Mover (http://www.heliumfoot.com/mercurymover/).

Comment: @Lawrence Velázquez, does that mean there's a way to move a window with the mouse *without* clicking the top of the window?  'Cause that should fix my problem too, right?